# How to load the .h5 file and do transfer learning using fastai?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, fast-ai

I have the pre-trained model in **.h5** format, how do I load it and do transfer learning using **fastai**?

I am currently using Keras to do transfer learning, but Keras doesn't have certain functionalities of fastai, the ones that I want to use are

> 1) `learn.lr_find()` 
>     2) `learn.recorder.plot()`

(to find the best learning rate) and

> 3) `learn.fit_one_cycle(2, max_lr=slice(1e-6,1e-4))`

(to use different learning rates for different layers).

I found some implementations in of the above functionalities for Keras but they had many issues.